# Voicemail Service with API

Tags: php, voicemail

I am looking for a service provider that will allow me to transfer calls to voicemail. Then I can use an API of there's (in PHP preferably) to access the voicemail and any metadata and then do with it what I like such as generating emails, tapping into a transcription service, etc...

I know that http://www.ribbit.com/ is new and looks like it might have some of what I need, however, I would also need a number to dial in to leave the message.

The company I am working for is developing a virtual receptionist that will allow them to forward calls to voicemail, so I would need a way to forward to a specific voicemail box for a specific customer.

Any suggestions, or does something like this not (yet) exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Tropo](https://www.tropo.com/).  It seems to have much of the functionality you describe, and a few more which will tickle you pink - including SMS service.  It's also free for development and cheap for production.

I don't work for Tropo or affiliates, i just have heard good things about the service.

Comment: +1 for linking to this, I'm enjoying this massively. They even host the stuff for you...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This looks like the perfect service for what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Consider [Twilio](http://www.twilio.com).  I've used them for a work project in the past.  It's cheaper than Tropo, though it has fewer features (like voice recognition).  They can still transcribe if I remember correctly (it costs extra, just like Tropo).  You should easily be able to script the behavior you want and hooking into their API.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. This also is a great service!

Answer (score 0):

I believe [Asterisk](http://www.asterisk.org/) is a very popular way to go. I use it for very specific purposes, and don't know much outside of my use, but it sounds like that might be a good solution for you. It's free, but you need a VoIP provider.

Comment: I had thought about Asterisk. I had reviewed it for an in-office solution compared to Ring Central which we currently use. In the future, I may have to migrate away from RC because of the volume of calls we'll be taking. At that time, this may be a great solution. I hadn't yet considered it. Thanks.